# Android Firebase Realtimetime database with recyclerview ondatachange

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Hi i am building a chat screen in which i am grouping chats according to date like WhatsApp but to group data i need to render data in reverse so i used **setReverseLayout** on my adoptor and **Collections.reverse(myChats)**  for data reverse and also **setStackFromEnd**  so that when new message comes it sticks to bottom but unfortunately it does not to scroll to bottom when chats are loaded also not scrolls to bottom when new message pops up. Can anyone tell me what is wrong in my code

**My Code**

```
 //Init Varibles
ArrayList<Message> myChats = new ArrayList<Message>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
private Boolean isUpdate = false; 


// OnCreate
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.messages);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
mAdapter = new MessageAdoptor(myChats,getApplicationContext());
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


// On Data Change
myChats.clear();
myChats.addAll(myChatsTemp);
Collections.reverse(myChats);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**Solution**

```
 recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```